# What are these components in a DHS/CBP Predator drone?

Tags: aircraft-systems, feature-identification, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, us-air-force

In the following diagram showing the "DHS/CBP UAS Platform Configuration", what are these components and what are they used for?

- PPDM
- SPMA
- RCM
- RVT encoder

[image: Slide showing diagram of the internals of a DHS/CBP UAS]

Answer (score 1):

[PPDM](https://www.parttarget.com/General-Atomics-Aeronautical-Systems_nsn-parts_UPA76073_8159184-000.html) is Payload Power Distribution Module

[SPMA](https://science.howstuffworks.com/predator.htm) is Sensor Processor Modem Assembly

[RCM](https://web.wpi.edu/Pubs/E-project/Available/E-project-042413-153504/unrestricted/Securing_Embedded_Systems_for_Unmanned_Aerial_Vehicles.pdf) is Rabbitcore microprocessor Core Module

[RVT Encoder](https://www.mitre.org/sites/default/files/pdf/09_0756.pdf) is a Remote Video Terminal Encoder

As for what they do, that is at least For Official Use Only. You could always submit an FOIA request.